# How do I measure the total weight of a container with scales on four corners?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, free-body-diagram, statics

I have a very large movable trash container, and I have mounted four scales, one on each corner. How do I get the **total weight** of the entire container? Is it simply a sum of the four weights, or is it more complex than that?

The contents of the container are not evenly distributed, one corner will be heavier than the others. Also, there is a possibility that one corner will not be completely resting on the ground, and thus the scale on that corner will read zero, but the other three corners will bear it's weight.

Comment: As long as everything is perfectly level it's just the sum of the weights reported by each scale.  The trouble you'll have is that if things aren't uniform and there is noticeable tilt in the container then the force won't be pressing perfectly orthogonally on the scale and it will report an incorrect reading.  Whether you can correct this with simple $\sin()$ or not depends somewhat on the mechanics of how your scales work.

Comment: You may want to do a sanity check where you add known weights and confirm that the weights on the scale changes as expected.

Comment: Or you can try shuffling the contents - if the sum of the weights don't change, then it is reasonably accurate.

Comment: Brandon, the tilt of the object relative to the scale surface is not relevant. The tilt of each weighing scale relative to the gravitational field of the earth is.

Comment: Guys- "tilt" ain't gonna matter, because nothing is in motion.  A spring scale will compress until the forces balance, and regardless of the slope of scales or container, since it's not moving the normal force has to equal $mg$

Answer (score 1):

it is the sum of the weights. it is common in large platform scales to have several individual load cells under the weighing platform, and then have an electronic circuit to do the summation.

note that it's also common practice to weigh a large multi-axle diesel truck and trailer by rolling one axle at a time over a small portable scale and then adding up the measurements from all the individual axles; this will equal the weight of the whole truck-and-trailer combination.